# Btrfs automatically bitrot correction with snapshots?

Tags: filesystems, partition, raid, btrfs, snapshot

I want to set up a notebook (debian) with **1 SSD** and **1 HDD** each with Luks and Btrfs on it. Because the SSD and the HDD doesn't have the same speed, i don't want to use **Btrfs' Raid-1** on it, but i also **don't want to miss Btrfs' checksumming and autocorrection**.

Now i am thinking about to use the HDD only for storing snapshots from the SSD. In the meantime i've found this https://superuser.com/a/1099181 , the script create the first time an initial read-only snapshot on the source drive (SSD) and later with example `cron`, an daily incremental snapshot with `btrfs send -p` and `btrfs receive`.

**My questions now:** If the SSD get some troubles for example **bitrot errors**, will and how will i know that this happens? I dont think that Btrfs on the SSD will automatically correct this errors the next time when i make an snapshot and use `btrfs send -p` with `btrfs receive`, because it is simply no **Raid-1**, am I right?

Btw, snaps on the same notebook but different drive aren't my (full) backup strategy.

Comment: do your btrfs filesystems have any redundancy (i.e. more than one disk in at least a raid-1 like configuration)?  if not then btrfs can not correct errors, it can only detect them, because there isn't a redundant copy to correct them from.

Comment: add a second SSD to match your first SSD, and a second HDD to match the HDD.  **THEN** you'll have redundancy on both the original and the backups fs.

Comment: I've clarified my question. If it's not possible to get an Raid-1 nearly function with Btrfs on this setup, i will buy an second SSD to use the 2 SSD with Btrfs Raid-1.

Comment: `zfs` has a `copies=` dataset parameter which can provide redundancy with only one drive (obviously, that can only protect against bad blocks, but not complete drive failure), but `btrfs` doesn't.  So redundancy on `btrfs` requires at least two drives per filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable mirroring / raid1 for the *metadata only* on the SSD. This would require manual error corrections (from a backup) though.

1. Split a single drive into two equal partitions
2. Create a BTRFS array with mirrored metadata and striped data. For example,

   mkfs.btrfs -d raid0 -m raid1 /dev/partition1 /dev/partition2

If files are corrupted, a btrfs scrub should detect them. Then you can restore the *hopefully* intact file from your backup. In this case, you'd want to complete a scrub before overwriting previous backups, or use versioning, or both.

Ideally, you'll automate the btrfs scrubbing and error reporting. I believe there are some btrfs maintenance scripts but I haven't tested them.